# How to create a fading label in JQuery / ASP.NET after a button press

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I think that this should be pretty easy but I'm not quite sure how to wire things up.

I have a page on which the user can define a query.  When done, the user enters a name for the query and presses a button.  I'd like to process the button click, make a text label (or Span) visible for a few seconds and then have it fade out.

Since it is a postback, I can turn an ASP:Label control to visible - that's easy.  Now how do I get jquery to make the label fade away after a few seconds?  In a broader sense, how do you get a postback to trigger a jquery method?

Bonus for the simplest solution!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start the asp label text as empty.

```
<asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Then you can fade out the label every page load and set the text of the asp label after hitting the button.

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
  myLabel.Text = "You hit the button"
End Sub

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myLabel').fadeOut(3000, function() {
            $(this).html(""); //reset the label after fadeout
        });
    });
```

Comment: I fixed the label name and changed innerHTML to html. See if this helps. If not maybe post some code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a low-tech technique that keeps all the script in your page template: add a `$(document).ready()` function to the page that executes conditionally based on a page-level variable, like this ...

```
// In your button's click handler, set this.UserHasClicked to true
var userHasClicked = '<%= this.UserHasClicked %>' == 'True';
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(userHasClicked) {
        $(labelSelector).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Took me a few tries until I figured out that this uses jQuery 1.4 (I was on 1.3) but it works like a charm. Thanks.  The only thing to add is that I have an "else" condition wherein I call hide() to hide the label.  I also didn't use an ASP:Label but instead opted for a div to hold the html/text.

Comment: Gah, I should have mentioned that. You're welcome for the part that didn't waste your time!

Comment: +1 and thx for the answer!  I used this at first but there were times when I need to change the text so I've switched to implementing  brheal's solution.

Comment: Now that I've read it, I prefer that solution too (for this requirement).

Answer (score 2):

Call [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
var buttonFade = function() {
  $('#my .label .selector').fadeOut(2000);
}
setTimeout(buttonFade, 2000);
```

If you post some of your markup, I could also take a stab at putting the setTimeout() into a function triggered when the label appears.